# EB - 4x4 Soft Keypad Driver Diagram from Makerstudio needed

Tags: arduino-uno, keyboard

I have found this interesting device wile looking for a cheap Arduino.
[image: 4x4 Soft Keypad Driver]

It's a "driver" that converts a [4x4 Keyboard 8-PIN (8-IO)](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Arduino-keypad-circuit.php) 
to [a 4-Pin (2-IO) Device](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/EB-4x4-Soft-Keypad-Driver/226959_1795573537.html)
I would like to know if is Achieved by a [shift register](http://forums.parallax.com/showthread.php/150719-4x4-Keypad-With-Four-I-O-Pins-(using-shift-registers)) ,[One Wire Keypad](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/OneWireKeyPad) or some other magic. If you have a diagram/tutorial/video please share (I know the "One Wire Keypad" uses Only 3-PINS (1-Analog-IO))Naturally ordered one to have a look but its gonna take some time to get here and i am way to exited.

Comment: If you can identify the chip that's on it that should give you all the information you need.  Chances are it's an I2C interface.

Comment: The chip is a tm1650. But I don't know how it is being used on makerstudio.cc their is a lib to use it.But i have not had time to use it yet .

Comment: Have you thought to ask Google then?  5 seconds, and I have Arduino library: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/TM1650 and datasheet: http://www.datasheetspdf.com/datasheet/download.php?id=840047 which though in Chinese has certain words like "SDA" and "SCL" in English. Like I guessed, it's an I2C interface.